# Is the MS Teams bot framework / botkit able to disable typing indicator?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, botkit-4

Is the MS Teams Bot Framework or botkit support a function to disable a typing indicator?

What I know that if want to start typing indicator then can use below format with value type is typing but how can I disabled the typing indicator once it start. Sometimes has case that typing indicator take long time to hide after bot response the answer.

```
    var data = {
        'type':'typing',
        conversation: 
        { 
          id: <channel>
        }
      };
```

Comment: Refer to this discussion on Teams uservoice https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/33683500-i-want-to-be-able-to-disable-the-notification-that

Answer (score 0):

Hi Muhammad Aiman Azizan,
As of now we cannot disable the typing indicator but you can raise your idea/voice in the link below,
https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/filters/new